# Find all the functions satisfying $\lvert f(x + iy) \rvert = \lvert f(x) + f(iy) \rvert$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, functional-equations, absolute-value, hyperbolic-functions

On the complex modulus page [from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html), I find an interesting statement:

> The *only* function satisfying identities of the form
>   $$\lvert f(x + iy) \rvert = \lvert f(x) + f(iy) \rvert$$
>   are $f(z) = Az$, $f(z) = A\sin(bz)$, and $f(z) = A \sinh (bz)$.

It refers to a paper that I cannot find on the Internet. It is trivial to show that these functions satisfy the identity, but why are they the only ones?

Comment: Presumably, MathWorld means analytic functions, since $f(z)=\overline z$ has this property.

Comment: This is not an answer for your original question. But, if we consider functional equation $f(x+iy)=f(x)+if(y),$ where $f$ is analytic in some region, then the only solution is $f(z)=az$ for some constant $a\in\Bbb{R}.$ This is an easy consequence of Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathworld entry seems to contain some errors.

First, the title of the paper is wrong, it should be "A curious trigonometric identity".  The paper available for free on jstor [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2310381).  The general idea of the proof is to replace the function by its MacLaurin series.

Second, it is missing the critical hypothesis that $f(z)$ is [regular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularFunction.html) for $|z|<r$ (presumably for any positive value $r$).

Comment: Is there any multi-valued function satisfying this equation?

Comment: No idea, I just tracked down the citation.